# Weblogic Grails 2.4.4 JSON Renderization

Tags: angularjs, json, grails, weblogic12c

I am using angularjs in a grails 2.4.4 application and in order to provide data to it, every request of my application has a JSON format response, like: 
`render object as JSON`

When I deploy it in Weblogic 12c, the respond is not returning the JSON correctly. I am obtaining a JSON that is not a JSON. This not happens in others servers.
For a better understanding look these image:

In Weblogic 12c I don't obtain a JSON object in the response

[image: the problem in weblogic12c]

Tomcat and Wildfly(Ok)

[image: In Tomcat and WildFly it runs OK]

Somebody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "not a JSON"? Edit your question and provide an example of what you are getting back.

Comment: I edited my question again. The only diference between the two requests I can see, is the "Server" entry