# Weblogic reload app throws "No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?" message

Tags: grails, deployment, weblogic

I have a grails-2.4.4 application deployed in weblogic 12c. The application works fine. However, when I stop and start the app, all GET action works, but not others [POST, PUT, DELETE, ...]. 
I got this exception message in console

> No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

I did some search and the solution everybody say is to add this line in web.xml file:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Grails generate its own web.xml file, and inside, this file has the following line:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

`GrailsContextLoaderListener` is an inheritance of `ContextLoaderListener`, so this is not my solution
What should I do?

Comment: This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885200/weblogic-grails-2-4-4-json-renderization